# Using chatGPT to cut unmatched text from the beginning and end of a source text and a translated text

Tags: string, nlp, translation, chatgpt-api

I'm trying to train a translation model to translate from English to Korean. The data I have are English books and its Korean translated counterparts. I need to pair each English sentence with its corresponding sentence in Korean.

The issue I have is that, because both are published books, they have some parts of text at the beginning and end that the other text does not have; things like publisher info about the original publisher of the English book, which the Korean version does not have; instead, the Korean one would have its own publisher info etc. The English original can have some acknowledgements or thank you notes at either the beginning or end of the book, which could be deleted or moved to back/front in Korean. Basically, the structure of the books is: garbage_text, main_text, garbage_text. I want to cut the garbage texts at beginning and end of both English and Korean texts so that what I have left is just the actual content of the books that match in meaning.

I want to use chatGPT to solve this, and with a small test case I made it performed fine. However, since I have a whole book from which I need to cut the beginning and end, I cannot fit it in one prompt. Which is fine, but I am not sure how I can do this if I split it up into multiple queries.

Comment: Please make your question sentence separate / stand out from the context description, make sure it is clearly state what you ask for.